# Current active virtual enviroment isn't shown in terminal

Tags: python, cmd, virtualenv

I'm using cmd on a windows 10 machine. Suddenly it stopped showing the currently active venv at the beginning of each command between round branckets (i.e. (venv) >> ). I'm sure the venv is active as I can see that the list of installed packages (with a pip freeze) is corresponding to the ones I have installed in the specific env. Thank you in advance for any advice to make it explicit again.

Comment: Do you have a Python directory in the PATH before starting the venv? What is the output of `where pip`? And, is `pip` coming from the venv?

Comment: Yes I have a python directory set as PATH, the output of where pip is made up of 2 paths, the path of pip.exe inside the venv and the path of pip.exe inside the base python folder

Comment: Which `pip` path is first? are you using `venv` or `virtualenv`? Have you tried starting the venv without a Python directory in the existing PATH variable?

Comment: The one inside the venv. I'm using virtualenv. No I'll try right now and let u know. Thank you very much

Comment: I tried removing python from the PATH variable but it's the same as before